# Rally: Fields from multiple tables

Tags: javascript, extjs4, rally

I am using the Rally WSAPI 2.0p5 with and the JSON return

I am looking to get fields from multiple tables in a single response. Is this possible? For example I am trying to get the User Story and also get the Iteration.State in the same data response. I know it is possible to do client side and if that is the only way. Can someone provide and example how I handle the async response to build the table (array).

Comment: Are you looking for the Iteration.State value to be populated when it is included attached to the Story?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question.

I would like the Iteration.State to be a field in the response from the WSAPI when I query the HierarchicalRequirement model. Presently there is an Iteration object in the return, but the object doesn't contain state information. It is just a reference object. Rather then looping through the return and making a second WSAPI call to Iteration   for every story, I would just like Status to be part of the first return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up for my original question. I recently came across the alpha release of the Batch Query WSAPI in Rally's WSAPI documentation. I would suggest the usage of the Batch Query to retrieve multiple Object Models in a single response.

As an example to get User Stories and get the Iteration Status in a single query.

```
{
    "stories" : "/HierarchicalRequirement?fetch=Name,Iteration,State&query=(Iteration.State = Accepted)"
}
```

The result is something that is more usable and doesn't require multiple queries to the server. i.e.

```
"Results": [{
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "40",
        "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/hierarchicalrequirement/xxxxxxxx.js",
        "_objectVersion": "17",
        "_refObjectName": "<user role> I would like <feature> for <benifit>",
        "Name": "As a <user role> I would like <feature> for <benifit>",
        "Iteration":             {
            "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
            "_rallyAPIMinor": "40",
            "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/iteration/xxxxxxxx.js",
            "_objectVersion": "4",
            "_refObjectName": "Sprint #",
            "Name": "Sprint #",
            "State": "Accepted",
            "_type": "Iteration"
        },
        "Project":             {
            "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
            "_rallyAPIMinor": "40",
            "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/x/project/xxxxxxxx.js",
            "_refObjectName": "Name",
            "_type": "Project"
        },
        "_type": "HierarchicalRequirement"
    },
    ....
    ]
```

For more information and a few resources:

- https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/index.jsp?version=1.40
- https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/batch.jsp
- https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/BatchScratchPad.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Simply add State to the list of attributes included in your fetch.  Rally's WSAPI will populate the value for sub objects even if the main type being queried does not have that field.

```
launch: function() { 
    var userStories = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', { 
        model: 'HierarchicalRequirement', 
        fetch: ['Iteration', 'State'], 
        autoLoad: true, 
        filters: [
            { 
                property: 'Iteration.State',
                value: 'Accepted' 
            }
        ], 
        limit: 10000, 
        listeners: { load: this._onDataLoaded, scope: this } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong. Here is a code snippet of what I am doing. The Iteration Name and State come back undefined when I attempt to log it.

Comment: <!-- language: lang-js -->
launch: function() {
var userStories = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
model: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
fetch: ['Iteration.Name', 'Iteration.State'],
autoLoad: true,
filters: [{
property: 'Iteration.Name',
operator: '!=',
value: ''
},{
property: 'Iteration.State',
operator: '=',
value: 'Accepted'
}],
limit: 10000,
listeners: {
load: this._onDataLoaded,
scope: this
}
});
}

Comment: I updated my answer above with your code.  Note the fetch attribute.